# Why must gravity have a quantum mechanical description?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, quantum-gravity

I know that to understand the Bigbang singularity or the blackholes, it is necessary to have a quantum description of gravity or quantum gravity. However, barring those kinds of explanations, is there any conflict of principles if gravity does not have a quantum mechanical description?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, it doesn't. Physics is descriptive, not prescriptive. We are trying to describe the world around us, not imposing or views on it. The universe could behave with two different rulesets with no apparent unification with them, that's a possibility. However, the tendency has been to realize that most systems are just particular realizations of a set of fundamental interactions, and furthermore that these interactions can then be unified. Therefore it is sensible to assume that the same can apply to gravity and quantum mechanics.